# Android Studio Выравнивание и отображение элементов

Tags: android, android-studio

View расположены в GridView, 4 строки, 3 столбца. Никак не могу добиться необходимой компоновки, и почему-то не отображается кнопка.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/WeekNum"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:entries="@array/catlist"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:tooltipText="Выберите неделю" />



<GridLayout
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lExNameFirst"
        android:text="Упражнение 1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgFirst"
        android:layout_width="159dp"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="0 / 100" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spFirst"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"></Spinner>

    <Button
        android:text="+"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="2">
    </Button>


    <ProgressBar
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="20" />

</GridLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Прилагаю картинку-сравнение, как есть (слева), и к чему стремлюсь

Comment: Используйте **LinearLayout**-ы для разделения пространства на части, а уже потом выравнивайте внутри них ваши вью элементы, при помощи `layout_gravity`. Ну или просто используйте **ConstraintLayout** )